# Can I be confident in purchasing food from a shop with a halal monitoring committee (HMC) certificate?

Tags: food, meat, halal-certification

I am double minded about ordering food from a grilled chicken shop. I see many Muslim brothers going there to eat now and then as the shop owner claims their chicken is 'halal', but the shop owner is non-Muslim.  The person on the till is a Muslim and he too claims it is halal. The shop also have an Halal Monitoring Committee (HMC) certificate.

On that note, should I be confident in purchasing food from there? What if the chicken is really not halal and maybe once it was on inspection. Will I be committing a sin for buying and unknowingly eating from there repeatedly?

Comment: If the shop has a valid *(not expired)* certificate and it is displayed, and there is Muslim guy telling you its Halal, then you shouldn't doubt it. You can also go to this link to check [HMC Certified Outlet](http://www.halalhmc.org/certified-outlets.htm).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about halal certificates

Comment: and to me it seems you are asking us whether to trust the halal certificate or not. Which is a behavioural question

Comment: What religion is the shop owner? Meat is also halal if it comes from Christians/Jews.

Answer (score 2):

You said the person on the till is a Muslim and he claim that the meat is halal. That is enough to buying food from them. If in future you understand that the food was not halal there is no sin for you.